# Нужно ли ставить тире в данном предложении? Если нет, то почему?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Нужно ли ставить тире в данном предложении? Если нет, то почему?

> Они выяснят у него (-) в чем он нуждается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этом предложении ставится запятая: ***Они выяснят у него, в чем он нуждается.***

Это СПП (сложноподчиненное предложение) с придаточным изъяснительным, союзное слово В ЧЕМ. Запятая является основным знаком, а тире — знак дополнительный, для него нужно обоснование.  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142

У Розенталя тире ставится для **интонационного отделения** главной части сложноподчиненного предложения от придаточной. В частности указано: тире часто употребляется в тех случаях, когда главной части предшествует придаточная изъяснительная.

В нашем случае это выглядело бы так: *В чЁм он нуждается — они выяснят*. Или: *В чем он нуждается — это они выяснят у него*.

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря, не знаю, в результате каких таких соображений, но хочется поставить двоеточие.

*В чем он нуждается: это они выяснят у него.*

Comment: Спасибо вам за участие в форуме.  Вероятно,  вы видите здесь значение пояснения (изъяснение и пояснение вообще тесно связаны между собой).  Но для постановки двоеточия требуется ИНТОНАЦИОННОЕ ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ: значительно увеличенная пауза и понижение голоса перед ней. Я могу предложить такой вариант с двоеточием:  «Они выяснят у него слЕдующее: в чем он нуждается». В этом предложении использовано слово, требующее пояснения. Похожий пример из Розенталя:  Я боюсь одногО: чтобы переутомление наших людей не отразилось на их работе. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=143#pp143